# Angular 6: Nested <li> tags are performing horribly bad with an *ngFor Angular

Tags: html, css, html-lists, angular6, ngfor

I am using **ngFor** directive to display a hierarchical list of elements using the **li** tag.

**Plunker URL : See code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-li-tag-performance)**

**When the records are huge(5k-10k)**, the browser takes a lot of time rendering. After analyzing the performance snapshot, I found that most of the time is taken in **calculating & applying styles**.
**Note:** I am not using any custom css or styles. Out of the box bootstrap css is getting applied for **li** tags.

If I swap the **li** tag with **span** tag the performance increases **100 folds**.
I believe, since span tag is an inline element, the out of the box bootstrap css doesn't apply and performance is good.

I have already tried using **[trackBy](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/#whentousetrackby)** but no effect.

**How to scale performance of nested li tags with ngFor directive**?

Comment: did you check the performance without generating it live? you are using for loop and its sync operation, So your browser will be in "stuck" mode until he finish to generate, and then it will populate the view.

Comment: @dAxx_: Thanks for the insight. I am not suspecting the *ngFor directive or the generation of elements since span tags are working pretty fast. It it the list tags(styling ?) which is taking a lot of time